# Fixed Table header after some distance of scroll

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have a table with TABLE HEADER and rows data. My row and column data goes past beyond page display limit so want to have only TABLE HEADER fixed.

Using below code able to manage to make TABLE HEADER fixed.

```
<tr style="position:fixed;z-index:999;top:190;left:230;background-color:#fff" > 
<th width="235" style="font-size:12px;text-align:left"  ><strong><u>List</u></strong></th>
<th width="200" style="font-size:12px" ><strong><u>Booking Details</u></strong></th>
<th width="100" style="font-size:12px;text-align:left" ><strong><u>Available Numbers</u></strong></td></th></tr>
```

Above this TABLE HEADER (of around length `190px`) I have WEBSITE HEADER.

Problem:
I want to make this TABLE HEADER fixed once WEBSITE HEADER passes above on scroll and when TABLE HEADER just about to reach top of the page. ie I want to make TABLE HEADER fixed after some distance of down scroll is done.

Please help

Comment: If jQuery is an option this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033191/how-to-detect-if-an-element-has-scrolled-out-but-only-once.

Comment: Hi Slacker and FoolishSeth, Thanks for your valuable input!! This is how need it. Please check the Table seen in the link. http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/

Comment: Hi, This is what I wanted!! below reference!! https://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/htmlfloatingtableheader/src/tip/tables.html